# How to upgrade windows 8.1 to 10 using sd card

Tags: windows, sd-card

I have linx 8 tablet PC with windows 8.1 installed. Internal disk space is 32 gb of which about 15 Gb is free now. But while trying to upgrade it to Windows 10,  it is showing low disk space. Then I installed 32gb sd card of which about 30 Gb is free (formatted as NTFS). I also have changed default download location of c drive to sd card by right click c:/users/downloads > Properties > Location > sd card. But still, a dialog box is showing low disk space. There seems to be no effect on changing location of Download folder. There is only last day of free upgrade. Please tell me how to set up the SD card so that during upgrading it uses the SD card to store the  files required.

Comment: There are only two ways of obtaining the Windows 10 upgrade: Windows Update or Upgrade Assistant. The Upgrade Assistant will only allow you to download an ISO or make USB media... You could download the ISO and, if you can install some ISO mounting software then you may be able to run the installer from the mounted ISO and do the upgrade like that?

Comment: I used upgrade assistant but it showed me low disk space. I dont know how to make ISO image. Would you please give me tutorial link from where I can learn ISO image making on sd card.

Comment: Runt he Upgrade Assistant and the only two options (under "make upgrade media for another computer") are to make USB media or download an ISO. Use this option and it will allow you to select the location where the ISO will be saved to... You don't "make" the ISO - it's already ready to download. You can then use an ISO mounting software (magic-ISO, I think, is at least one) and it will run the ISO as if you'd just inserted the disk

Comment: Since you asked this today, I hope you realize, the offer already expired

Comment: Although, Microsoft declared last day of free upgradtion is 29 July 2016, I am able to upgrade my tab to Windows10 today 30 July 2016. Thanks to @Big chris, You helped me a lot. I downloaded ISO but not by Upgrade Assistant but by Windows Media Creation Tool. Upgrade Assitant has no such option. Also, Windows 8.1 has built in ISO mounting utility. Just to right click of dowloaded ISO > Properties > Location > Change > Windows Explorer. It will take around 20-30 seconds before Windows 10 installation begin.

Comment: Sorry, Media Creation Tool - my apologies!

Comment: Try downloading the Windows 10 iso and installing it through that, since the free upgrade period is over.